# QGIS 2.4 mapRenderer.extent() does not equal mapRenderer.setExtent()

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Could anyone help explain this QGIS 2.4 python console code? I would expect the return value of `.extent()` to be the same as the bounding box given to `.setExtent()`:

```
mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
llx=729200
lly=4361200
urx=736400
ury=4368400
rval=mapRenderer.setExtent(QgsRectangle(llx,lly,urx,ury))
print "  lower left = "+str(llx)+","+str(lly)
print "  upper right = "+str(urx)+","+str(ury)
print "rval:"+str(rval)
print "mapRenderer.extent():"
e= mapRenderer.extent()
print e.toString()

>>>execfile(u'C:/Users/Tom/Documents/extent_test.py'.encode('mbcs'))

  lower left = 729200,4361200
  upper right = 736400,4368400
rval:True
mapRenderer.extent():
727776.0840998685453087,4361200.0000000000000000 : 737823.9159001314546913,4368400.0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

QgsMapRenderer.setExtent() takes into account the current output size of the map renderer. The extent will be modified to match the same width/height ratio as the output size. That's why your vertical coordinates remain unchanged, but your horizontal coordinates are modified to preserve this ratio.

Comment: ok thanks - I was poking around with some of the other methods of QgsMapRenderer and discovered something like what you say:  .setScale and .setOutputSize and then setExtent will lead to .extent() returning the expected values.  But, I'm worried that I'm not doing those in the optimal or expected sequence.  Is there a tutorial page on the 'best' sequence of method calls for setting up an instance of QgsMapRenderer?

Comment: If you're using QGIS 2.4 and above, then QgsMapRenderer is actually deprecated and you're better off using QgsMapSettings. The online api docs for QgsMapSettings are much more extensive: http://qgis.org/api/2.4/classQgsMapSettings.html